# Almost Topology

Tags: general-topology

Helly everybody,
I'm trying to find another approach to topology in order to justify the axiomatization of topology. My idea was as follows:

Given an **arbitrary** collection of subsets of some space: $\mathcal{C}\in\mathcal{P}^2(\Omega)$
Define a closure operator by: $\overline{A}:=\bigcap_{A\subseteq C\in\mathcal{C}}C$
This gives rise to a topology apart from the space itself being open.
However, considering the space as being equipped with a notion of being close, all topological question can be studied - as in topological spaces.
*(I left out the details as being part of my research)*

So my question is:
*What could go BADLY! wrong if a collection would satisfy all axioms for open sets but the entire space not necessarily being open?*

Thanks for your help! Cheers Alex

Comment: Sorry but I downvote because this question misses any motivation. Otherwise we will have here thousands of questions like "what happens when we drop transitivity in the definition of partial orders" etc. ...In principle the removal of certain axioms should be motivated by some explicit application. So you can improve your question by writing down a natural(!) example of an "almost" topology.

Comment: Moreover, you're throwing out more than just that. Take the union of all open sets in your topology and you should get the whole topology, but that's the whole space which you're saying isn't open! Then the arbitrary union of open sets is no longer open. Then your definition of a topological space really isn't expanding on the notion of 'openness' in the reals at all, which was the point to begin with (at least in early topology).

Comment: @mathematics2x2life: It's one option that the space *is* in fact open; or that not every point is contained in an open set. Which is really what's going to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearness Spaces

Such a space wouldn't constitute a topology in the open set definition, though it would give rise to some sort of space in which "being close" still makes sense for **all points** to subsets.

Imagine the following situation:
$\Omega:=\mathbb{S}^2\cup\{\mathbb{B}^3\}$
$d(x,A):=\lVert x-A\rVert$ (in the usual sense)
In this example there would be a point being close to every subset:
$\forall A\subseteq\Omega:\quad\mathbb{B}^3\in\overline{A}$

Answer (score 7):

In fact, the consequences are of leaving out this axiom are rather dull.

Let $X$ be such an *almost topological space*. Now let $$Y\subset X$$ be the supset of all elements of $x$ such that there is an open set $U\ni x$. Taking the union of all such open sets $U$ you see that $Y$ is open and every open set is contained in $X$. In particular, the open sets induce a proper topology on $Y$.

Thus we see that $X$ is the union of a topological space $Y$ and some pathological points $X\setminus Y$ which possess no open neighborhood at all.

Answer (score 1):

If the whole space $X$ is not open, then constant functions might not be continuous, depending on the definition chosen for "continuous."

Comment: But isn't continuity more or less a local property in which one not necessarily has to prove it for all opens but only the ones gettin smaller and smaller. As far as I know there are even examples in which one has to restrict in metric spaces epsilon being smaller some upper bound in order to get positive results.

Comment: Well, yes, normally. But if you retained the definition of continuity as being "the inverse image of an open set is open," then a constant function might not be continuous. So you'd have to abandon either continuity of constant functions, *or* the characterization of continuous functions I mentioned.

Comment: Hmm, ok good my idea was anyway to define continuity in another fashion as being continuous at some point iff it preserves closeness: $$\overline{A}\owns p \Rightarrow \overline{f(A)}\owns f(p)$$ ...what do you think can happen in that case?

Comment: Well, with the usual definitions, points in the complement of the union of all open sets are in the closure of the empty set, so a constant function to a point which has a neighbourhood will not be continuous at these points.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done.  But it is not very interesting.
Any of these equivalent versions of "topology" could be used its starting point:

(1) In axioms for open sets, do not require the whole space to be open

(2) In axioms for closed sets, do not require the empty set to be closed

(3) In axioms for a "closure" operation $\tau$, do not require $\tau(\varnothing) = \varnothing$

(4) In axioms for "neighborhood", do not require the collection of neighborhoods of a point to be nonempty

(5) In description of net convergence, do not require a directed set to be nonempty

**added**

Nothing "really bad" happens.  But also nothing interesting happens.  We can write an almost topological space $X$ uniquely as a disjoint union, $T \cup Z$, where $T$ is the "topological part", the maximal open set in $X$, a topological space in the usual sense; and $Z$ is the "extra part", the closure of the empty set in $X$, which has no topological structure at all.

Maybe the only use is as a counterexample, showing why we should require a directed set to be nonempty.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I'm thinking of. Can you tell me what might  REALLY BAD happen?